# AutoComplete VerticalAlignment

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using [MaterialDesignExtensions](https://github.com/spiegelp/MaterialDesignExtensions). I'm however unable to put the AutoComplete 
in the center.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" IsChecked="False" 
                x:Name="MenuToggleButton"/>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <controls:Autocomplete Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignAutocompleteDense}" 
                               AutocompleteSource="{Binding Path=AutocompleteSource}" Hint="Which OS?"
              Background="#A5D6A7"     
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplateDense}" />                            
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Sample output:

[image]

As you can see, the border in the bottom in the image represent the StackPanel so the control is clearly not centered.

Comment: Try setting `VerticalAlignment=Center` to the `StackPanel`.

Comment: @kennyzx  It's weird because I had a textbox and I didn't have to that but It did work, thanks!